# C# Files Are Missing In Custom .Net Standard Library Project Template

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-standard, project-template

I am trying to create a custom .net standard library project template. My custom project template contains some .cs (C# Files) files.

I have created a project template using **Project => Export Template option in Visual Studio 2017**. The exported zip file contains the .cs file. But when i try to create a new project using my custom .net standard library project template, .cs (C# files) files are missing in my newly created project.

Am i missing something or there a new way to create project template for .net standard library.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've got the same issue. The files are in my zip, and I've set `<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>` but my Program.cs and some of the publishing settings won't load in the template. (Mine is net core 2.0)